# getting error Object DOMDocument sould be created in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, error, blocks, dependency-injection

```
<?php

namespace Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Windowclosepopup extends Template { public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Netzwelt\Winclosepopup\Model\Grid $gridFactory,
    array $data = array() ) {
    $this->_modelFactory = $gridFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data); }

public function getCollection(){
    return $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection(); }
    /**
     * Get base url without store code
     */
    public function getBaseUrl() {
        return $this->_storeManager
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
    }

    /**
     * Return  config value by key and store
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\Store|int|string $store
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getConfig($key)
    {
        $result = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue($key,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        return $result;
    }
    }
```

This error is in line `parent::__construct($context, $data);`

Can anyone provide me the solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that **you don't inject the right `Context` class in your constructor.**

As your class extends the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` you have to replace :

```
\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context
```

With:

```
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context
```

In your constructor arguments in order to fix your issue.

Comment: seems this is new unbreakable record, someone who posted more number of answers in 24 hours, hats off champ....

Comment: Thx .Raphael   let me check it .

Comment: @Raphael - I have posted one more question visible on first question page . Can you plz check that also ?

Comment: Thx Raphael its works..